# fasttext keeps predicting one label

Tags: text-classification, fasttext

am trying to use fasttext to label some data `[url]`or`[PN]` just to test it
after training on **6k** of each label and upon predicting it keeps predicting [PN]

training command

```
fasttext supervised -input input.txt -output model -minn 0 -maxn 0 -epoch 100 -lr 0.1
```

sample training data

```
__label__PN 5962-8904XA
__label__PN 585DD4P54ZP
__label__PN GQ0B11400FCT
__label__URL http://ws.com/qd/lat/ispls32883.pdf
__label__URL http://ws.com/pdfs//2004/0423/ds/m412b.pdf
__label__URL http://ws.com/pdfs//2004/0423/mc68.pdf
```

sample test data

```
945
74ACT399MTC
http://www.msn.com/mylink.pdf
MQ8797BH
74AC1153
ICL762PA+
54LS3482A
54LS76A/B
54HC27/A
www.google.com
```

Comment: try replacing special characters with spaces and setting the minn and maxn parameter

Answer (score 1):

FastText it's based in the [WordNGrams](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.01759), it means that you need to be ***a complete sentence*** as input for the algorithm.

In your example, you're passing only a unigram for the algorithm, and depending on the number of `WordNGrams` that you're using in the parameters you model is not able to learn.

[ELI5](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ELI5): The algorithm it's saying: I'm able to learn complex sentences because the structure of the words and their combination, but you're sending to me only words. I cannot handle that.